# Set shipping cost on the product, fix configurable products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I extend the flatrate carrier model of Magento 1.9 as suggested [here](http://blog.aajit.com/product-level-shipping-in-magento/) because I want to set shipping cost on the single product.

When I add configurable products in the cart, shipping cost is double.
Magento consider inside the cart a configurable product and simple product variant.
So when I add a configurable product Magento sum shipping cost of both configurable and single products.

I add a condition to exclude configurable products. Is it ok? Is there a way to extract only single products from the cart?

Thanks.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $cart_items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $custom_ship = 0;
    foreach( $cart_items as $items ){
        // items are configurable and single products
        $cur_fproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items->getProduct_id());
        if($cur_fproduct->getTypeId()=='simple') {
            $custom_ship +=($items->getQty())*($_helper->productAttribute($cur_fproduct, $cur_fproduct->getShippingWorld(), 'shipping_world'));
        }
    }

    return $custom_ship ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on this,

```
$cart_items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

use,

```
 $cart_items = $session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Or you can check

```
foreach( $cart_items as $items ){
        // items are configurable and single products
        if ($item->getParentItemId) // this is set for simple products of configurable
       { 
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!
I also check the difference between getAllItems(); and getAllVisibleItems(); here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042905/difference-between-two-commands-of-fetching-shopping-cart-items-in-magento